# Winbind dont start when secutiry = ads

Tags: samba, winbind

I have samba and Winbind over ubuntu server with the following smb.conf

```
[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   password server = 192.168.1.1
#  security = ADS
   winbind use default domain = yes


# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

   syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

   encrypt passwords = true

   passdb backend = tdbsam

   obey pam restrictions = yes

   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

   #pam password change = yes
   username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
   map to guest = bad user
```

if i try to uncommend the "secutiry = ADS" when restart winbind dont start

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? How about the logs?

Answer (score 2):

Did you install and [configure Kerberos then join the domain etc?](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/domain-member.html)

> SECURITY = ADS
>
> In this mode, Samba will act as a domain member in an ADS realm. To operate in this mode, the machine running Samba will need to have Kerberos installed and configured and Samba will need to be joined to the ADS realm using the net utility.

Comment: yes i have krb5 and configured and use `net ads join -S PDC -U Administrator`